# SSRS - How to export data to a single excel spreadsheet when using report pagination?

Tags: sql-server, excel, reporting-services

I have a 2012 SSRS report that process thousands of records, it's a paginated report via an SSRS parameter.

When we export the report, the data is being sent to multiple spreadsheets (due to the pagination).

Is there any way to avoid this? To keep pagination but export the data to a single spreadsheet?

Thanks

Comment: If it's in a single table, it usually is exported to a single sheet. If there's grouping, there might be a page break between groups. Are you doing something to force new pages? Are the sheets named differently in Excel?

Comment: Yeah, I'm using pagination with grouping, =CEILING(RowNumber(Nothing)/20). That's why its being sent to different spreadsheets.

Answer (score 0):

There are two different kind of "pages" when viewing a report. There are natural breaks based on the page size and then there are hard page breaks that can be set to occur between objects or groups.

With hard page breaks it's all or nothing. The sheets created during export are a direct reflection of the page breaks in the report.

However, if you simply let the report create pages during viewing and don't specify any actual page breaks, all the data will export to one sheet!

Answer (score 0):

Another hack way of doing this is.. have another version of the same report without the group pagination. Hide this report. Have a text box on your original report.. call it "Export to Excel" or something like that.. under actions for the textbox.. select go to URL. and in there put in your report server path to your hidden report.. including any parameters in your original report.

The link would look something like this - Note the Command at the end of the URL:

```
"http://yoursite/ReportServer/Pages/Folder.aspx/Production%20Reports/?%2fProduction+Reports%2fYOUR_HIDDEN_Report"&"&parameter1=" & Parameters!parameter1.value &"&parameter2="& Parameters!parameter2.value,& "&rs:Command=Render&rs:Format=EXCEL"
```

You have to play around with the link to get the correct link.. Once you have the correct link.. run the original report report and click on the "Export to Excel" Button / text box .. You will now see a prompt to download the Excel file..

You should not have a as a single sheet.. done.